# My user is destroyed when I log out of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, logout

I'm at a loss here.  I have three Devise scopes (legume, vegetable, & fruit)

I have one user table and legume, fruit, and vegetable tables reference it:

- User has one Legume, Fruit, and Vegetable
- Legume, Fruit, and Vegetable belongs to User

I'm able to logout out just fine with 2 of the 3 scopes, but there is one scope (fruit) where I logout and my user is erased from the database.  I receive this error message after I logout.

> translation missing: en.devise.sessions.fruit.destroyed

I am logging out using the following code:

```
    link_to "Logout", destroy_fruit_session_path, :method => "delete"
```

Here is the output in the logs:

> Started DELETE "/fruits/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-11 21:43:58 -0400
>     Processing by Fruits::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
>     Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2MwwcPF4NTWUUXDXiAh+v0B85CPNeUrW+R7S78FWo9E="}
>     User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 335 LIMIT 1
>      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
>     SQL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 335]]
>      (1.3ms)  COMMIT
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/fruit/login

Ugh!  I feel so stupid!!! I figured out my own problem and it is pretty embarrassing...

Instead of overriding my SessionsController with Devises's SessionController I accidentally overrode it with the Registrations Controller which deletes the user on destroy.

I had

```
    #incorrect!!!
    class Fruits::SessionsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

Instead of

```
    #correct...
    class Fruits::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

Comment: You mention that you haven't overridden Devise's destroy logic, but have you overridden anything else in Devise?

Comment: I only override Devise as a last resort.  I normally try to work with it.

Comment: OMFG...I did the exact same stupid thing (the perils of copy&paste)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
:method => :delete
```

instead of

```
:method => "delete"
```